# Birt: Setting row and crosstab Dispaly property to none through javascript

Tags: javascript, birt

I want to hide a crosstab by clicking on a button. I have created a text element and inside it, I am calling a javascript to set the display property of both row and crosstab to none. The row is a fixed height and I have set the overflow property of the cell to scroll so that the crosstab does not go to the next page

Below is what the crosstab looks like originally

[image: Cross tab without any change]

The problem is that when I set the display:none for both row and crosstab, I can still see empty iframe with scrollbar as below.

```
document.getElementById("crtGridRow").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("crosstab").style.display = "none";
```

This only happens in Internet Explorer. In FF and other browsers, It hides fine

[image: After hiding crosstab and gridrow in Internet explorer]

Now here is the second Issue. When through another button, I turn the Display to block

```
document.getElementById("crtGridRow").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("crosstab").style.display = "block";
```

In Internet Explorer, the Crosstab and its data shows fine but in FF and other browsers, the crosstab does not show up. Instead I can see an empty space that seems to be the space for the crosstab but I only see a white space

[image: Crosstab after showing up in Firefox]

Can someone please help me fix this issue

Arif